# OpenGL - glDrawElementsInstanced - fragment shader and incorrect colors

Tags: opengl

I have created instancing, that correctly display geometry, but its graphics is incorrect.

My VS look like this

```
#version 410

#include "engine-variables.inc"
#include "functions.inc"

in vec3 POSITION;
in vec3 NORMAL;
in vec2 TEXCOORD0;
in mat4 INSTANCE_TRANSFORM;

out vec2 vTexCoord; 
out vec3 vNormal;

void main() 
{ 
    gl_Position = CalcPositionInWorld_Instance(POSITION, INSTANCE_TRANSFORM);

    vNormal = NORMAL;   

    vTexCoord.x = TEXCOORD0.x; 
    vTexCoord.y = 1.0 - TEXCOORD0.y; 

}
```

*Note: `#include` is processed by my app - not part of glsl*

I have simple fragment shader

```
#version 410

in vec2 vTexCoord; 
in vec3 vNormal;

out vec4 fCol;

uniform sampler2D en_texModel;

void main() 
{ 

  vec4 texVal = texture2D(en_texModel, vTexCoord);

  fCol = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) + 0.00001 * texVal + vec4(0.00001 * vNormal, 0);

}
```

*Note: 0.00001 values are there because of debugging, when I need to hold texVal and vNormal variables for refractoring within my app.*

Result is incorrectly colored. Model is not red, but black and white (randomly distributed over triangles) - only few triangles are red

[image]

Comment: A negative value for vNormal.x could still cancel out the red channel, if it is large enough. Can you change your statement to fCol = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1); to make sure this is not the case?

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity Ah... thank you.. put your comment as answer and I will accept it

Comment: I would avoid using the pre-processor directive `#include` in your shader. While it is not part of GLSL proper, there exists an extension that allows you to replace this directive with shader strings (`GL_ARB_shading_language_include`). Obviously GLSL has no notion of a filesystem, so the names used with GLSL's `#include` pre-processor extension refer to named shader strings (`glNamedStringARB (...)`). If this extension ever goes core, you will be hijacking a perfectly valid GLSL-reserved pre-processor directive. Something like appending `_` to the end of custom directives would avoid this.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Most of my shaders comes from HLSL, where include exist. I dont have single shader, i have built them to effect using other files that have notion of my filesystem. So only drawback might be when include will be official part of glsl. Otherwise, I dont see any problem at all.

Comment: @MartinPerry I think you misunderstood my point, the fact that GLSL's `#include` directive does not use a disk-based filesystem was not the issue here. The issue is that GLSL already has a pre-processor directive called `#include`. Right now it is only an extension, but your shader uses a word that will be reserved by unextended GLSL's pre-processor in the future. It is better to avoid collisions like this simply by renaming your custom directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the line:

```
fCol = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) + 0.00001 * texVal + vec4(0.00001 * vNormal, 0);
```

Which can still result in a black color if either texVal.x or vNormal.x is large and negative, cancelling out the red color from vec4(1,0,0,1).